# How get specific Post from FacebookClient by Post-ID

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm trying to get a specific post (by ID) with the C# [Facebook-SKD](http://facebooksdk.net/)-Client.

The Load-Method to load the x last entries works fine.

```
var client = new FacebookClient(Token);
dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
parameters.limit = 10;
dynamic results = client.Get("hslu.ch/posts/", parameters);
```

Returns as expected the latest 10 Posts from the Posts of the Site.

Is there a way to load only post X with the ID Y_Z?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
var client = new FacebookClient(Token);
dynamic results = client.Get("Y_Z", new ExpandoObject());
```

This would be the equivalent of a request to `https://graph.facebook.com/{version}/{node-id}`. More info in the [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.3#reading)

Answer (score 0):

And If you want to get the Specific Post's

1. Likes count
2. Comments Count
3. Who likes
4. Who Comments
5. what comment posted
6. Likes count for comments posted

Here you go [How to get Number of shares and Likes for a URL using FacebookGraph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32701732/how-to-get-number-of-shares-and-likes-for-a-url-using-facebookgraph-api/33030188#33030188)