# How to get Number of shares and Likes for a URL using FacebookGraph API

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-c#-sdk

How to get Number of shares and Likes for a URL using Facebook Graph API? There are a few posts answering a similar question but every post offers a different method/fb API.

I am using the C# SDK and I guess I should be using the Graph API since FQL is not supported in the latest FB API.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7707810) looks nice but the poster said the returned value for shares is sum of shares and likes for this URL and I need them separately.

Answer (score 2):

After Posting post into facebook you will get Post ID(138885734110127_1484064888656364) in return from facebook. Using that post id you can get counts of likes and comments and who likes and comments, and what comment posted. I don't know about shares.

For getting likes and comments here is the code:

```
            var fb = new FacebookClient("Your Access token here");
            var WallPost = fb.Get("138885734110127_1484064888656364");


            JObject jObj = JObject.Parse(WallPost.ToString());
            var Comments = jObj.Property("comments");
            var Likes = jObj.Property("likes");
```

You will get in json. Hope this helps. :)

Comment: If this helps means you can select this as answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think I maybe rather late, but here is my code for getting shares,likes and comments for URL, please observe that it doesn't require an access token, hope this helps in some way!.

```
string url = "http://www.youtube.com";     
string QUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/?fields=id,share,og_object{engagement{count},likes.summary(true).limit(0),comments.limit(0).summary(true)}&id=" + url;

        System.Net.HttpWebRequest Request = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(QUrl);
        Request.ContentType = "text/json";     
        Request.Timeout = 10000;
        Request.Method = "GET"; 
        string content;


        using (WebResponse myResponse = Request.GetResponse())
        {
            using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(myResponse.GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                content = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }
        };

        var json = JObject.Parse(content);

        var like_count = json["og_object"]["likes"]["summary"]["total_count"];

        Console.WriteLine("Like Count :" + like_count);

        var share_count = json["share"]["share_count"];

        Console.WriteLine("Share Count :" + share_count);

        var comment_count = json["og_object"]["comments"]["summary"]["total_count"];

        Console.WriteLine("Comment Count :" + comment_count);
```